# Is it possible to update index settings by query?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I updated the index settings from readonly to writable by running this command:

```
PUT index_name*/_settings
{
  "index.blocks.write": null
}
```

However, I'd like to rever this to readonly for some documents within the index. Is it possible to update the settings for specific documents?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is an index-wide setting. You've set it on multiple indices using the `index_name*` wildcard so the only thing you can do now is unset it either using the same wildcard or by targeting an individual index.